# Looking for an alternative solution to processing tens of thousands of JSONs from Azure Blob to Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, etl, pipeline, databricks

I currently have pipelines developed that leverage Azure Data Factory for orchestration and Azure DataBricks for it's compute to perform the following actions... I receive tens of thousands of single record json files into Azure Blob in a real-time basis and on a 15 minute basis i check the folders for any new files and once found I load them into a dataframe using Databricks and load these into a single file in SQL DB before having other ADF jobs trigger stored procedures which then transform my data into final SQL tables.... We are looking to move away from Databricks as we are not using it for it's true capabilities but are of course paying the Databricks costs. Looking for ideas on other solutions to load tens of thousands of jsons into SQL DB (with minimal to no transformations) on a periodic (i.e. 15 minute) basis. We are a microsoft shop so not looking to necessarily move away from Azure tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a few ideas:

- use Azure Functions + Blob Trigger / Event Grid to process the JSON files in real time (every time a new JSON file arrives, it will trigger your function). Then you could either insert into the final table or on a temporary table.
- another idea would be combine Azure Functions + Blob Trigger / Event Grid to sink the data to a data lake. You can use ADF to sink it to SQL final tables.

Comment: the SQL Server concurrent connections limit is 2400 for a 24 core machine. This would be exceeded as we are having tens of thousands of files landing every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL DB is actually pretty capable as far as JSON goes so you could just use `OPENROWSET` to import the data directly from blob store and `OPENJSON` to shred it.  You could then use a Logic App running on a schedule to call the proc say every 15 minutes, you wouldn't even need ADF as part of the solution.

I've worked up a couple of similar answers previously, eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457704/azure-data-flow-creating-managing-keys-for-identity-relationships/62460836#62460836) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60300293/how-to-map-json-data-from-a-rest-api-to-azure-sql-using-data-factory/60352494#60352494), but let me know if you want to progress more down this route and we can work up something more detailed.

Comment: I would consider this way and would like to avoid ADF due to the mapping limitations. Our jsons aren't consistent either. they are coming from a database that only sends the fields that are populated. Not all fields that are existing at the source for each record.

Comment: I am considering using Azure Batch as well.